# Average calculation in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in MS SQL Server like below:

```
ID    | CLIENT
--------------
123   | D    
444   | D    
555   | E
```

And I need to calculate how many ID is per CLIENT. SO as a result I need something like below:

```
CLIENT | avg_id_per_client
---------------------------
D      | 1.5
E      | 3
```

- D = 1.5 because there are 2 CLIENTS "D" and there are 3 CLIENTS in general, so 3 / 2 = 1.5
- E = 3 because there are 1 CLIENT "E" and there are 3 CLIENTS in general, so 3 / 1 = 3

How to do it in MS SQL Server ?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Hint - *window functions*

Comment: shouldn't it be D=2/3 & E=1/3? 66% + 33% = 100%

Comment: One more time, asking [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70778265/61305) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70773781/61305) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70769297/61305) again without adding any information to the question, like what you tried and why existing solutions you've already been provided don't work, doesn't make anything better. It's just going to steamroll every account you try to use into a question ban.

Comment: LukStorms not, because I need to have number of ID per CLIENT not percentage share, do you undertand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SUM OVER a COUNT.

> ```
> SELECT CLIENT
> , COUNT(id) AS client_total_id
> , CAST(AVG(1.0*COUNT(id)) OVER () AS FLOAT) AS average_count
> , CAST(1.0*SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER () / COUNT(id) AS FLOAT) AS odd_avg
> , CAST(100.0*COUNT(id) / SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER () AS DECIMAL(5,2)) 
> AS percentage_id
> FROM your_table
> GROUP BY client
> ```

| CLIENT | client_total_id | average_count | odd_avg | percentage_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 2 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 66.67 |
| E | 1 | 1.5 | 3 | 33.33 |

But you probably want this

> ```
> SELECT CAST(AVG(1.0*client_total_id) AS FLOAT) AS avg_id_per_client
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT client, COUNT(id) AS client_total_id
>   FROM your_table
>   GROUP BY client
> ) q;
> ```

| avg_id_per_client |
| --- |
| 1.5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=090409b36c8c38ef288b033a9946a313)*

Comment: Tank you! it works perfect :) Best answer was given

Comment: Luk, could you tell me on which question answer column "odd_avg", what this column presents?

Comment: It gives the results for your expected `avg_id_per_client`. But personally I see no meaning in it.  F.e.  if the total count for all clients is 1000,  and a client has count 1, then `odd_avg` would be 1000/1=1000.  That's not an average.

Comment: Yeas, you are right, I just relized now, I need an answer to a specific question: how many IDs per CLIENT on average, do you know how to answet on this kind of question based on my sample data ?

Comment: it would be (2+1)/2.  `AVG(client_total_id)`

Comment: could you add it to your answer please Luk ? because when I add simply avg(COUNT(id)) I have error that it is not possible to aggregate other aggregation function

Comment: Sure, see update.